# Getting line geometry out of two points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have one input point layer and out of that, I want to create an output LINE vector layer.

For each feature in my output line vector layer, I define a geometry which takes 2 point geometries. Figuratively speaking, imagine a line which connects both points -> this should be the line feature I want to add to my output layer!

I have tried it like this:

```
newEdge = QgsFeature(outFields)
geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geomFrom.asPoint(),geomTo.asPoint()]) # The error happens here!
newEdge.setGeometry(geom)
```

This had worked for me in QGIS2.x, but with QGIS3, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 194, in processAlgorithm
>   TypeError: index 0 has type 'QgsPointXY' but 'QgsPoint' is expected

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try:  QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(geomFrom.asPoint()),QgsPoint(geomTo.asPoint())])

Answer (score 7):

Try the following

```py
points = []
pt = QgsPointXY(0,0)
points.append(pt)
pt = QgsPointXY(1,1)
points.append(pt) 
fields = some_layer.dataProvider().fields()
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
feature.setFields(fields)
feature.setAttribute('id', 1)
some_layer.addFeature(feature)
```

I do not know the reason but pyqgis 3 works only with QgsPointXY and prefers creating polyline by QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY().
I discovered this case when like you adapted some code from Qgis 2.18 - Python 2.7 to Qgis 3.2 - Python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `QgsPoint` and `QgsPolyline`, a list of `QgsPoint`s (standalone script using a memory layer but you should replace `vl` with the reference to your own layer)

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "temp", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

with edit(vl):
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("id",  QVariant.Int)])
    vl.updateFields()
    points = []
    pt1 = QgsPoint(0,0)
    points.append(pt1)
    pt2 = QgsPoint(1,1)
    points.append(pt2) 
    fields = pr.fields()
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points))
    feature.setFields(fields)
    feature.setAttribute('id', 1)
    vl.addFeature(feature)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```