# Creating line geometry from latitude/longitude dictionary

Tags: qgis-3, geometry, pyqgis-3, polyline-creation, dictionary

I want to create LineString geometry between points, based on a latitude/longitude dictionary.

My code worked in QGIS 2.x but in QGIS 3.x, my new shapefile is empty.

I have replaced `QgsPoint` and `fromPolyline` by `QgsPointXY` and `fromPolylineXY` but it doesn't resolve my problem.

My code is below:

```py
self.writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(path_layerout, self.fields, QgsWkbTypes.LineString, crs, transform_context, save_options)

for (ky, vals) in points_dict.items():

    for i, v in enumerate(vals[:-1]):

        start = vals[i]  # lat
        end = vals[i + 1]  # lon

       self.feat = QgsFeature()
       self.verticies = [QgsPoint(start[1], start[2]), QgsPoint(end[1], end[2])]
       self.feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.verticies))
       self.feat.setAttributes([str(start[0]), str(end[0])])  
       self.writer.addFeature(self.feat)
```

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: [@BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32958/bera), here is a question for you :-)

Comment: Where do you start and end editing? In my other answer you mentioned, there is a block `with edit(vl):` https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/365742/638 You need to use it to say when you edit. Normally, all the block `for (ky, vals) in points_dict.items():` should be within a `with edit(self.writer):` but could be wrong (not tested, just clue)

Comment: @ThomasG77 You couldn't use `with edit` with QgsVectorFileWriter, but indeed I forgot to mentioned that I delete the writer with `del self.writer` at the end of my code. In facts, in the .dbf of my new shapefiles, attributes are well writing but the shapefile don't have any geometry..

Comment: Why do you try first to use the `QgsVectorFileWriter` whereas you could use in memory layer, check it's fine and save it with `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`? Do not adress your issue directly, just another way to solve the same issue.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the dictionary to your question?